# Extracting templates from templated class

Tags: c++, templates

I'm trying to extract the type pack off an instance of a template class:

```
template <template <class T, class... Ts> class>
using first_in_template_class = T;
```

I tried this and other similar variants, but I get this error:

> unknown type name 'T'

How to go about this?

P.S. I know I can use `std::tuple_element` in the `std::tuple` case, but I'm looking for a way to extract types from templated classes.

Comment: Version without `tuple_element` is easy to write, have a look at [this site](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters), section *Template template arguments* and example with `eval` template, all you need to do is to add `using type = T1` in specialization. [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/443465d595efa292)

Comment: @rafix07 This makes a lot of sense, thanks. Do you know if there is a specific reason template template parameters are not in scope for using declarations (or even classes where they need to be passed separately?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use:

```
template <typename T>
struct extract_first {};

template <template <typename...> typename ClassTemplate, typename... ClassTemplateParams>
struct extract_first<ClassTemplate<ClassTemplateParams...> > {
    using type = typename std::tuple_element<0, std::tuple<ClassTemplateParams...> >::type;
};
```

Comment: Nice idea, just using `tuple_element` to do the heavy lifting :) BTW, you don't need to post a different answer if you make a mistake. Just edit the first answer instead.

Comment: @Anonymous1847 Thanks this works great! This seems like a bit of a hack though. I wish C++ would support the code in the question (edited)

Comment: @Kostas Believe you me, this is among the least hacky things you can see with template meta-programming.

Comment: I'm not sure why you switched to `std::tuple` utilities rather than using an additional deduced parameter and matching `ClassTemplate<First, Rest...>`?

Comment: @Quentin cleanliness and brevity mostly.