# Determining what data type a templated struct holds

Tags: c++, templates

So I have a data structure that looks a bit like this

```
#include <vector>

template<typename T> struct Vector 
{
    std::vector<T> v;
};
typedef Vector<int> Vi;
typedef Vector<float> Vf;
typedef Vector<double> Vd;

template<typename T> struct Matrix
{
    std::vector<T> m;
};
typedef Matrix<Vi> Mi;
typedef Matrix<Vf> Mf;
typedef Matrix<Vd> Md;
```

Now in the body of `Matrix`, I want to know what data the underlying `Vector` holds, so that I can use it in a function. Here is an example in invalid c++ to clear up what I am saying.

```
template<typename T> struct Matrix
{
    std::vector<T> m;
    //type = typeid(m[0].v[0]).name();
    //void somefunction(type arg);
};
```

Comment: you can make use of `decltype`

Comment: For standard types you have the type member `value_type`. For custom templated containers, you can use something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64795375/extracting-templates-from-templated-class

Comment: In C++17, this might be a good use case for std::variant and std::visit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can retrieve the type using `declval` and `decltype`:

```cpp
template<typename T> 
struct Matrix
{
    std::vector<T> m;
    using type = typename decltype(std::declval<T>().v)::value_type;
};
```

Or you can use an intermediate structure to extract the type from `Vector`, see :

```cpp
template <class V>
struct VectorType;

template <class T>
struct VectorType<Vector<T>> {
    using type = T;
};

template<typename T> 
struct Matrix
{
    std::vector<T> m;
    using type = typename VectorType<T>::type;
};
```

Comment: Possible edge case for `vector<bool>` where `operator[]` does not return `bool`.

Answer (score 4):

See the "Member types" section of [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector):

```
Member type     Definition
value_type      T
```

As such, for an `std::vector`, you can retrieve the value type, e.g., by using:

```cpp
template<typename T> struct Matrix
{
    std::vector<T> m;
    using value_type = T::value_type;
    //void somefunction(type arg);
};
```

I would suggest that you expose something similar in your `Vector` class. Personally, I find that having such a publicly accessible type is preferrable to the `decltype` approach, which is unnecessarily complicated:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <vector>

template<typename T> struct Vector 
{
    using value_type = T;
    std::vector<T> v;
};
typedef Vector<int> Vi;
typedef Vector<float> Vf;
typedef Vector<double> Vd;

template<typename T> struct Matrix
{
    using value_type = typename T::value_type;
    std::vector<T> m;

    void somefunction(value_type arg);
};

typedef Matrix<Vi> Mi;
typedef Matrix<Vf> Mf;
typedef Matrix<Vd> Md;

int main() {
    std::cout << "Mi uses " << typeid(Mi::value_type).name() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In the OP's example, `T` does not have a `value_type` memeber as `T` is a `Vector`, not a `std::vector`.

Comment: Ah, missed that. I'll add a comment explaining that the `Vector` should expose something similar.

Comment: @mrks This didn't work for me when I copied and pasted your `Matrix` to replace mine.

Comment: @mrks says `class "Vector<int>" has no member "value_type"` when I try to instantiate `Mi` as `Mi mat`

Comment: Did you add `value_type` to your `Vector` class? `using value_type = T;` in `struct Vector`

Comment: @mrks Nope, didn't know that was needed. But now when I try to compile after adding that it gives an error: `syntax error: identifier 'value_type'` and a warning: `'T::value_type': dependent name is not a type`

Comment: Argh, I should be more careful. I updated my answer to contain the full (tested...) code.